# Meaning of "Form" in mathematics

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, analytic-number-theory

There are a number of occasions in the mathematics where the word "form" is used:

- [Modular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form)
- [Bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form)
- [Quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form)
- ...

It seems that *form* is a special kind of *function*.

But I cannot readily see what properties a function should satisfy to be eligible to be called a form?

Comment: I've always been told that a form is just a function with codomain $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: There is also [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

Comment: I think the usage is historical but deeply ingrained and comes from the days when functions were thought of as having algebraic representations as opposed to the arbitrary functional relations that we think of in  the modern set-theoretic approach. So a quadratic, or bilinear or differential or ... form referred to the algebraic form of the representation of the function. (But this is really a mathematics history question and I am not qualified as a historian.)

Comment: See [of the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_the_form). Also [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OftheForm.html).